# Android show ProgressDialog before socket.connect

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am trying to show a `ProgressDialog` before I call `socket.connect()` in my Android Application. Unfortunately the dialog only appears **after** the `socket.connect()` method is finished. Here is what I do:

```
public void connect() throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(remoteActivity, "Connecting", "please wait...");

        socket.connect(sockaddr,timeout);

        ipAddress = socket.getLocalAddress();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());   

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I know I could use a different Thread to call `socket.connect()`, but I don't want this method to run asynchronously as I want to use the Exception mechanism.

Comment: Proper use would dictate the use of a separate thread. If you use a separate thread, there's nothing stopping you from using exception handling in that thread. It would actually be preferred.

Comment: But I want to wait for that method to be finished before I continue. If I use a seperate thread for that I would need some synchronization. I have tried to work with `wait()` and `notify()` but I always ran into an Exception. Do you have an example of how to do this properly?

Comment: What prevents you from using Exception mechanism and worker threads at the same time? Other thing is that you'll get a NetworkOnMainThreadException if you'll work with sockets on the UI thread.

Comment: I understand that if your application is currently not adapted to use threading, then you'll have to change some of your workflow to rely on threading callbacks instead of just running straight-through. However, when it comes to UI updates occurring on background processes, you'll be glad you did. What if you wanted to change the text progress dialog as the background thread progresses - how would you do this without using a separate thread?

Comment: Here's a link that may help with Java callbacks, and working with asynchronous calls: http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

Comment: Handling the socket connection actually is done in another Thread. It's just the initial call to `connect()` that is triggered from a button press in the UI-Thread. My biggest problem is that I need to wait for the connect() to be finished before I can use `writeObject()`. But I realize that the proper way to do this is in fact to use a different thread here, so I'll try to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never perform Networking operations or in matter of fact any Input/Output in the `Main/UI Thread`. on top of that android introduced [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) to force the developers to avoid using the main thread for netowrking . this thread is meant to

- Update User interface components.
- receive and generate events for the user.

anything except that better be done in a separate thread. now regarding the `Exception` mechanism you can use a Boolean indicator instead that the connection succeeded or not.
if you incest on getting the exception back here is a way to pass it back:

```
private void handleException(Exception e){
 // do whatever you want with the exception
}
public void connect() {

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(remoteActivity, "Connecting", "please wait...");
    final Handler handler = new Handler():
    new Thread(){
     @Override
    public void run(){
     try{            
        socket.connect(sockaddr,timeout);

        ipAddress = socket.getLocalAddress();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());   
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
          });
      } (catch(final IOException e)
        {
          handler.post(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                    handleException(e);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
          });
        }
    }.start();

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works pretty well. Now I just have to wait for the connect() method to be finsished before I can actually use the socket.

Comment: I would *not* use Threads for this. Please use AsyncTasks instead! Or AsyncTaskLoaders: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html , https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston please specify the drawbacks when Discouraging using a specific tech or API

Comment: I described the difference in a google-groups here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/x_7dovdXhjE/7JQxMxtLn2wJ

Comment: It is not wrong perse, but using AsyncTasks are usually preferred over Threads when delivering results of background work to the UI. I think this explains it well (see the *Worker* *Threads* section): http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

Create custom class, extend `ProgressDialog`, put connection into constructor and call connect method inside override show function

Answer (score -2):

Try to preempt your thread so the UI has chance to  act. For example:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(remoteActivity, "Connecting", "please wait...");
Thread.sleep(1);
socket.connect(sockaddr,timeout);
```